# How to Get a User List from Azure Actice Directory (Native App)?

Tags: c#, azure, native

I want to get a list of users who have the right to use the application.

It is not possible to enter Secret keys in the Native App. I try to use the same accessToken as I log in. Authentication works fine. ObjectId is the same as my native app ObjectId.

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, _ADClientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Never));

string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

var groupFetcher = (IGroupFetcher)activeDirectoryClient.Groups.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.First(g => g.ObjectId == "5deedc8c-2ba6-45d8-a4f2-xxxxxxx");
```

Error: Authorization_RequestDenied

What went wrong?

Comment: Now, reading is OK, but I can not get users. The group name is displayed correctly, but it does not have any members or owners? I started a free AD Premium trial, did not help. [Image](http://pirttinen.net/pub/members.png)

Comment: Now started to work :) ObjectId has to be the same as Group ObjectId. And wait for the premium account to take effect. Big thanks to Martin.

Comment: If is useful, you could mark it as an answer to help other communities who has the same issue.

Comment: I will do this as long as I get enough reputation points first (now 11). I can not yet give points to others. Reqires 15 points.

Answer (score 1):

Within your Azure Active Directory, go to your Application registration and add a **delegation** permission for the Windows Active Directory API. Im not sure which is the least permission you can select (maybe Sign-in and read user profile may work) but Read directory data will give you the necessary permissions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already given those rights. How do I see if I have admin rights? I am on the owners list, but how to determine the admin?

Comment: Which admin rights you mean? AAD or for the Resource? Also, you don't need admin rights to browse users.

Comment: Read directory data, Requires Admin -> Yes.

Comment: Ah okay, its the AAD Admin. You will find it on the user tab I think under Directory Role. Also, did you clicked the Grant permissions button after you changed the permissions?

Comment: Thanks!  That I had not pressed just save.  Now I get the error that there is no match. This is already progress :)